# How to create this type of custom switch button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to create this type of custom button in flutter.

[how to create this type of custom button in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjqlo.jpg)

Comment: Check if this plugin could help:-https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_toggle_tab

Comment: I hope this will work for you after some modification. https://github.com/savadmv/swipe_button_flutter